# Laravel add variable for nested collections

Tags: laravel

I want to add variable to each object of collection inside collection. Here JSON response like this:

```
         {
         "id": 16,
          "survey_id": "8",
          "title": "How are you?",
          "created_at": "2020-02-06 04:21:44",
          "updated_at": "2020-02-06 04:21:44",
              "answers": [
```

Here I want to add variable to each answer

```
{
            "id": 52,
            "question_id": "16",
            "text": "VERY GOOD",
            "created_at": "2020-02-06 04:21:44",
            "updated_at": "2020-02-06 04:21:44",
            "reports_count": "4",
            "responded": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 53,
            "question_id": "16",
            "text": "OK",
            "created_at": "2020-02-06 04:21:44",
            "updated_at": "2020-02-06 04:21:44",
            "reports_count": "4",
            "responded": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 54,
            "question_id": "16",
            "text": "BAD",
            "created_at": "2020-02-06 04:21:44",
            "updated_at": "2020-02-06 04:21:44",
            "reports_count": "2",
            "responded": 2
        }
    ]
},
```

Overall, I want to add for every answers variable like `$respond = $answer->reports()->count();` Help PLease!!

Comment: from which variable you get the output or from where you get the results. Put some details please

Comment: $qq = Question::with(['answers' => function($query){
            $query->withCount('reports');
        }])->where('survey_id','=',$id)->get();

Comment: foreach ($qq as $question){
            $answers = $question->answers()->get();

            $question->answers->map(function($spec) use ($answers){
                foreach ($answers as $answer){
                    $count = $answer->reports()->count();
                    $spec['responded'] = $count;
                }
                return $spec;
            });

        }

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, if you want to calculate it in the collection directly.

```
$yourCollection->transform(function($collectionItem) {
  $collectionItem['responded'] = $collectionItem->answers->count();
  return $collectionItem;
});
```

But you could do this also on the sql side. I think it should be also the better way ;)

Comment: Hello! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would fetch the answers from the database before assigning that array to a new question-object-property.

```
public function get() {
  // fetch parent question
  $question = Question::where('title', $title)->get();

  // fetch answers
  $answers = Answers::where('parent_id', $question->id)->get();

  // create property called "answers"
  $question->answers = $answers;

  return response()->json($question);
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you!